# How do I save pictureBox1.Image with the current drawings inside?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

In form1 I have pictureBox1 Paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, factor, distance);
  pictureboximagestosavecount++;
  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\temp\pboximages\" + 
      pictureboximagestosavecount.ToString("D6") + 
      "pbimg.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
  anglecounter += 1;
  DrawLine(e.Graphics, anglecounter);
  if (null != mImage)
  {
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, mRect);
  }
  DrawRectangle(e.Graphics);
}
```

When I'm running the program I see the DrawLine I see cloudEnteringAlert and the image I see everything on the pictureBox1.

I added now the saving line:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\temp\pboximages\" + 
                         pictureboximagestosavecount.ToString("D6") + "pbimg.gif", 
                         System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

I'm getting many images gif's on  my drive but they are the same I don't see the CloudEnteringAlert and not the DrawLine only the image itself. I guess I'm not saving the changes only the Image. Then how can I save it all the time including the drawings of the CloudEnteringAlert and the DrawLine ?

EDIT:

This is what i did now:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            anglecounter += 1;
            DrawLine(e.Graphics, anglecounter);
            if (null != mImage)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, mRect);
            }
            DrawRectangle(e.Graphics);

            pictureboximagestosavecount++;
            savePictureBox(pictureBox1, @"c:\temp\pboximages\" + pictureboximagestosavecount.ToString("D6") + "pbimg.gif");
        }

        void savePictureBox(PictureBox PB, string fileName)
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PB.ClientSize.Width, PB.ClientSize.Height))
            {
                PB.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PB.ClientRectangle);
                bmp.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            }
        }
```

I have timer3 tick event that make pictureBox1.Invalidate(); each 10ms
I need it 10ms interval since i want the drawings in the paint event to be smooth as possible and also fast.

And since i call savePictureBox in the paint event each 10ms it make everything very slow.

This is timer3 tick event. Timer3 interval is set to 10ms since i want that the drawing in the method DrawLine to be fast.

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: The Paint event of any Control lets you draw onto the Contols surface. What you seem to want is drawing into the PictureBox's Image. This can be done anywhere else you want. You don't use the Paint.e.Graphics but a PictureBox.CreateGraphics() for this. Of course that means that you have changed the Image.  If you don't want that you can ask the PictureBox to drawitself Image and surface onto a new Bitmap, which you can then save. The Call is PictureBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp)

Comment: You should explain us how often you want to save and how often the drawing happens! To advise you best we need to know the event flow you want to have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you probably are looking for:

```
void savePictureBox(PictureBox PB, string fileName)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PB.ClientSize.Width, PB.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        PB.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PB.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

It saves the `PictureBox` complete with `Image`, `BackgroundImage` (if there is one) and everything drawn onto it in the `Paint` event.

If instead you actually want to modify the Image say so..

Comment: Updated my question. Since i'm calling this savePictureBox method inside the pictureBox1 paint event it's making everything very slow.

Comment: Well, first: The Paint event is hardly the right place for the save, as it is not only called by your Ticks but also by outside event. So if at all put the call in the Tick! Second: Wrinting an Image every 10ms is indeed way too fast. (That equals 100fps - Even movies run at 15-25fps, not 100!!) In fact anything faster that 35-75ms is too fast for a normal Timer. Maybe you want to a) set your Timer down to 30-50 ms and use another Timer to take those images at a pace your machine can support..

Comment: Right used another timer with 1000ms interval to take the images. I will play with thi timer interval to get the best speed for taking the images. Thanks.